# Uploaded image is Empty - iOS AFNetworking PHP MySQL

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c

I'm uploading an image to the server using AFNetworking. everything seems to be working fine. However, when I check the image folder, the images are 0 bytes. `empty cannot be displayed.`

My PHP Code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');


include 'connection.php';
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$username = $_POST['username']
$image = $_POST['image'];

$sql = "SELECT id FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC";

        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        $id = 0;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $id = $row['id'];
        }


$path = "images/$id.jpg";

$actualpath = "http://www.example.com.au/ios/$path";

$sql = "INSERT INTO photos (image) VALUES ('$actualpath')";

 if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
    $response["Result"] = "TRUE";
    $response["message"] = "Successfully Uploaded";
 }


}else{
        $response["Result"] = "FALSE";
        $response["message"] = "Nothing";
    }

echo json_encode($response);
$conn->close();
?>
```

and im using following Objective C code.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": _username.text,
                             };

        [manager POST:@"http://example.com.au/ios/addUser.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"image"];
            }
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {}
```

After running the code I'm getting success response from the server but the images are empty.

Comment: Instead of `$image = $_POST['image'];` use/try `$image = $_FILES['image'];` since we're dealing with "files" and not text. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried using `$_FILES` still same. ill check error reporting

Comment: you can also try echoing all your variables and `var_dump()`'ing your query and variables to see what's passing/or not. If this is and IOS issue, I won't be able to help you there. Good luck and Happy Holidays, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the above code from tutorial [Link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-using-php-mysql-android-studio/). and dont know how they able to do it. after research in internet and finalized the code like below. and it work fine.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$newfilename = $username . '.' . end($temp);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "./images/" . $newfilename)) 
{

    $response["Result"] = "TRUE";
    $response["message"] = "$newfilename";
} 
else
{
    $response["Result"] = "FALSE";
    $response["message"] = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

$actualpath = "http://www.example.com.au/ios/images/$newfilename";
$sql = "INSERT INTO photos (image) VALUES ('$actualpath')";

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```